# CSS margin affects active href

Tags: css, button

I have a div which I need to position 30px from the bottom of the elements above it. When I do, the cursor no longer works but only on the edges of the div. I have tried position:absolute and top:30px, still same result. I cant figure how to have all the div be active when the cursor rolls over and position it. Any help?

```css
.headernavbuttons {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #861622;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-weight: bold
}

.headernavbuttons:hover {
  background-color: hsla(14, 45%, 15%, 1.00);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px
}
```

```html
<div class=headernavbuttons onclick="location.href='https://tcokchallenge.com/launch2/inquire-now/'">inquire now</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? When I place the corsor over the DIV, the hover effect applies as it should (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` has a border-radius, i.e. rounded corners. Making the corners rounded will decrease the area of the `<div>`. To make this trimmed area clickable, wrap your `<div>` in another `<div>`, move the click listener to the outer `<div>` and modify your CSS this way:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.headernavbuttons {
  background-color: #861622;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-weight: bold
}

.wrapper:hover .headernavbuttons {
  background-color: hsla(14, 45%, 15%, 1.00);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" onclick="location.href='https://tcokchallenge.com/launch2/inquire-now/'">
  <div class="headernavbuttons">inquire now</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to have multiple buttons on the same page?  Right now with your code when I hover on one button it activates all

Comment: Put each button in a separate wrapper `<div>`.